# In which case do I need to run a DNS server daemon?

Tags: linux, dns

After reading the theories of DNS server, I'm still not 100% understand its use case. We need DNS to resolve a domain name e.g. `drive.google.com` to its IP address. If I check my desktop PC with Fedora OS, the named process is not running. I've installed the *bind* package and can run the *named* process with `sudo systemctl start named`.
However, without this process I can use the internet in my desktop until now.

So my questions are:

1. When do I need to install and run the DNS-Server in a computer or single board computer (raspberry pi)?
2. What happens if I runs the DNS server daemon in my desktop PC?
3. Is the DNS server runs only in the computer servers from the internet providers or in our routers?
4. How about in windows server, what is the name of the DNS process running in windows?
   Thanks

Comment: 1. One use-case: I run bind as dns server for my mailserver to let spamassissin query dnswl without errors.

Comment: Another use-case: Privacy(?). But in general, I guess when you don't know that you would need to run it, you don't need to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We need DNS to resolve a domain name e.g. drive.google.com to its IP address

In this case you almost certainly do not need to run your own nameserver. You can, but you will gain very little. What you need is something else, such as a standard ISP consumer-grade NAT/Modem/Router that handles DNS lookups on your behalf.

1. *When do I need to install and run the DNS-Server in a computer or single board computer (raspberry pi)?*

   You only need a DNS server if there isn't one present on your local network and you need central management of your own local domain name/address lookups. Most of the time, most people do not need to run their own DNS server - they can use either a DNS server provided by their ISP or they can use public ones such as 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8.
2. *What happens if I runs the DNS server daemon in my desktop PC?*

   Nothing unless you use it. And even then you'll see no gain unless you need to provide your own name/address lookups.
3. *Is the DNS server runs only in the computer servers from the internet providers or in our routers?*

   I run an internal DNS server (several, actually) for my organisation. They handle internal lookups for internal machines that the rest of the world does not need to know about. They also handle public name/address lookups for external systems that we want to reach.

   My public DNS servers provide lookups for the rest of the world to reach a small selection of servers that offer public services (our website, for example). Often this service is provided by a third-party company - typically the one that lets you register your domain name(s) - but there is no restriction on you running your own public DNS server(s).
4. *How about in windows server, what is the name of the DNS process running in windows?*

   You would install the DNS Server role

Comment: "In this case you almost certainly do not need to run your own nameserver." Installing a local caching recursive nameserver (ex: unbound) does help in many cases. Not strictly necessary, yes of course.